# Problem binding a boolean property using a lambda [Java - JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8, binding

I'm new JavaFX and lambdas in Java.

I'm developing a little cards game project and am currently writing the interface, which I want to bind to the model using "beans" ('hb' below), each bean having some properties (e.g: playableCards(), hand()).

The images[i] represent the images for each card in the player's hand, and I want to bind their opacity to whether the card is playable or not.
When trying to bind the properties in a for-loop I came across the following problem :

I cannot pass the loop index to the lambda. ( I get the following error when compiling : "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final")

After trying many alternatives that didn't work for binding an object property to a boolean one, I found this solution that uses a lambda :

```
BooleanBinding bb0 = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
hb.playableCards().contains(hb.hand().get(0)), hb.playableCards());

images[0].opacityProperty().bind(Bindings.when(bb0).then(1).
otherwise(0.2));

BooleanBinding bb1 = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
hb.playableCards().contains(hb.hand().get(1)), hb.playableCards());

images[1].opacityProperty().bind(Bindings.when(bb1).then(1).
otherwise(0.2));
```

etc... for the 9 images of which I want to bind the opacityProperty().

As you can see, there is a ton of code repetition. Like I mentioned earlier, when trying the "logical" solution :

```
BooleanBinding[] bb = new BooleanBinding[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < Jass.HAND_SIZE; i++) {
        bb[i] = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> hb.playableCards().contains(Bindings.valueAt(hb.hand(), i).get()), hb.hand());
        images[i].opacityProperty().bind(Bindings.when(bb[i]).then(1).otherwise(0.2));
    }
```

I stumble against the "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" problem, I get what it's telling me, but I can't seem to figure out a workaround.

Is there any solution as to avoid writing the entire code for each property?
It does work but it's a little cumbersome.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Bindings.valueAt(hb.hand(), i).get()`: It makes little sense to use this code unless the list may not contain `i+1` elements. Otherwise `hb.hand().get(i)` achieves the same effect in a more optimal way...

Comment: @fabian Yes, indeed, I for got to replace that part, thank you. But I still have the i that causes problems

Comment: @fabian By the way, you marked this topic as duplicate, do you happen to know the link to the answer to this problem? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: ??? The link is right at the top of your question: Basically you create declare a new variable inside the loop body and assign the loop variable to it. You could also retrieve the `Card`(?) object outside of the lambda, which has the same effect (note that this could potentially change the results on a modification of the hand). `final Card card = hb.hand().get(i); BooleanBinding bb = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
hb.playableCards().contains(card), hb.playableCards());`

Comment: @fabian Sorry for the trouble, I have not used Stack Overflow very much and didn't see you put the link over there. Thank you very much for your answer!